# WP-CLI Bulk delete posts from specific category

Tags: posts, wp-cli, bulk

I would like to know how to bulk delete posts from a specific category using the [WP-CLI](http://wp-cli.org/), any tip?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This should delete **all** posts in your category:

```
wp post delete $(wp post list --cat=your_category_ID --format=ids)
```

**Or** directly:

```
wp db query [<your_sql_query>]
```

For more info:

```
wp post delete --help
wp post list --help
wp db query --help
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually update wp-cli needs to use the following command to delete all products for a category of Woocommerce installation:

```
wp post delete $(wp wc product list --category=category_id --user=admin_username) --force
```

Since Woo only allows to delete 100 products per time you can use the following **bash command to create loops using a step value of 100.**

```
for run in {1..2}; do wp post delete $(wp wc product list --category=category_id  --user=admin_username) --force; done
```

this one deletes 200 products in 2 steps of 100 product each

```
for run in {1..3}; do wp post delete $(wp wc product list
--category=category_id --user=admin_username) --force; done
```

this one deletes 300 products in 3 steps of 100 product each

and so on...