# Plugin exceeds memory limit

Tags: plugins, php, plugin-development

I'm bulk deleting posts from my WordPress site using the function `wp_delete_post` and categories using `wp_delete_category`. That are about 100.000 posts and 4.000 categories, and after a while I get a PHP Error

`PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of ... bytes exhausted`

That's what I do inside my code:

```
// get all IDs from the posts and categories
$delete_categories = $wpdb->get_col("SELECT DISTINCT(j.term_id)...");       
$delete_posts = $wpdb->get_col("SELECT DISTINCT(j.post_id)...");
$delete_parent_categories = $wpdb->get_col("SELECT tt.parent FROM $tbl_term_taxonomy tt ...");
// I removed the SQL statements for a better reading


foreach ($delete_posts as $dp) {
    echo "deleting post ".$dp."\n";
    wp_delete_post($dp, true);
    unset($dp);
}

unset($delete_posts);

foreach ($delete_categories as $dc) {
    echo "deleting category ".$dc."\n";
    wp_delete_category($dc);
    unset($dc);
}

unset($delete_categories);

foreach ($delete_parent_categories as $dc) {
    echo "deleting category ".$dc."\n";
    wp_delete_category($dc);
    unset($dc);
}

unset($delete_parent_categories);
```

Deleting the posts works, deleting some categories also works - but at some point the memory limit is exceeded and the script is terminated. Setting the memory limit to 1024MB doesn't look like a perfect solution for me.

Is there a way to free up the memory that the WordPress functions allocated?

Comment: This may not be a great idea but maybe loop like 500 (more or less) posts to be deleted at a time and then refresh the page. `header("Refresh:0");`

Comment: I think that's not possible, because the script is a standalone script and runs without a webserver - so a header won't do anything here.

Comment: So put it into a WordPress page template or call it like any other php file. How are you getting it to run at the moment?

Answer (score 2):

The code you use also uses WordPress functions that will first load posts (and other relevant data) in memory first and cache them using object cache. So, to delete 100.000 posts, your code will try to load each post in memory and that can take a lot of memory. I am not sure how high PHP memory is set in your case, but, you can either limit the deletion to 1000 or 5000 posts at once or increase PHP memory.

Comment: Can I manually clear the memory to free up space? Or should I repeatedly call the script as long as there are posts left and limit it to 5.000 posts per call?

Comment: Try to use 'wp_cache_flush()' function, it will clear the WordPress object cache. But, it is not a good idea to run it after each deletion, maybe call it after every 1000 posts deleted.

Comment: Nice! Didn't know such a function exists. Thanks, I'll try that.

Comment: It is much better idea to delete such a large number of posts using only SQL queries. It would be a complex query with multiple joins (to delete posts, post meta, comments and any terms posts can have), but it will be fast, and no PHP memory issues.

Comment: Do you know what I need to delete for each post? `post`, `postmeta`, `term_relationships` - there exist no comments or terms for the posts.

Comment: WordPress deletes from posts, postmeta (connect post.ID to postmeta.post_id), term_relationships (connect post.ID to term_relationship.object_id) and comments tables. And, after that, it has to run update for the terms counts.

Answer (score 1):

With so many posts to delete it is better to escape the limitations of the webserver and use wp-cli [relevant example](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/241543/wp-cli-bulk-delete-posts-from-specific-category). The other alternative is to not use a live server, but to offload everything to your local development server, run your code there, and upload things back.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend your first line of code be

```
wp_suspend_cache_addition( true );
```

This will stop the data from being added to the cache and bloat filling memory.